# Getting action events of buttons placed in a different component

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jpanel

Is it possible to display a button outside the component in which it is placed. My question seems weird, but the situation is: I have a JFrame. I also have a JPanel class in which I override the paintComponent() method, getPreferredSize() method etc. I create an object of the JPanel subclass and put it in the JFrame. So far so good. Now I want things inside the JPanel to behave according to a button click. But I don't want to place the button inside the JPanel because it will block some animation going on inside the panel. So I will place it outside the JPanel, maybe in another JPanel in the JFrame. But then how do I get the button click event which is occurring inside the second panel into the first.

Answer (score 1):

In this [animation](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway), `SubwayPanel` has access to a `ButtonPanel` that controls one aspect of the simulation. When the timer fires, `SubwayPanel` can check a button's state via `ButtonPanel#getButton()`.

Addendum: A more general solution is to use [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which "can be used to separate functionality and state from a component." Here's a related [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel).